# Scikit-learn updates in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, updates

Before asking the questions, I will make an introduction. The code below does not present any error, however, in theory the algorithm should graph *figure 2*, but graph *figure 1*. Looking for an algorithm similar to mine on the internet, I found it, but exactly the same problem occurs. I have also noticed that the libraries are being updated, and that each time they are better. I Compared the misclassifications samples of a flower type for *LinearRegression* and previously (I don't remember the version) there were 8 or 7, with the most recent version  the misclassifications samples are 1.

**Question 1:** Do I need to make any changes to the code to obtain *figure 2*? If the answer is no, what is the interpretation of *figure 1* ?. If the answer is yes, what should you modify and why?

**Question 2:** How can I see the library updates, specifically the scikit learn algorithms?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]]
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
sc= StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)


lr=LogisticRegression(C=100.0, random_state=1)
lr.fit(X_train_std,y_train)

weights, params = [], []
for c in np.arange(-5, 5):
   lr = LogisticRegression(C=10.**c, random_state=1)
   lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
   weights.append(lr.coef_[1])
   params.append(10.**c)

weights = np.array(weights)
plt.plot(params, weights[:, 0], color='blue', marker='x', label='petal length')
plt.plot(params, weights[:, 1], color='green',  marker='o', label='petal width')
plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
lr = LogisticRegression(C=10.**c, random_state=1, multi_class='ovr')
```

`multi_class` was one of the parameters that had default values changed in recent releases from scikit-learn. (The other parameter was `solver`). For some reason turning it into a binary problem solves the issue, but not much of a clue on what's going on to be honest. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, knowing that will help me know where I should look to answer my questions!